# RegEx with multiple groups?

Tags: python, regex

I'm getting confused returning multiple groups in Python. My RegEx is this:

```
lun_q = 'Lun:\s*(\d+\s?)*'
```

And my string is

```
s = '''Lun:                     0 1 2 3 295 296 297 298'''`
```

I return a matched object, and then want to look at the groups, but all it shows it the last number (258):

```
r.groups()  
(u'298',)
```

Why isn't it returning groups of `0,1,2,3,4` etc.?

Comment: I think what you directly refer to is called [Capturing a Repeated Group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) - or along the lines 'accessing every match in a quantified / repeated capture group'. see [this similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3537914/611007) for javascript. don't know for sure but ***they seem to be unsupported in python's regex flavor***. see [related python enhancement request](http://bugs.python.org/issue7132) and [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15908085/611007)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your regex only contains a single pair of parentheses (one capturing group), so you only get one group in your match.  If you use a repetition operator on a capturing group (`+` or `*`), the group gets "overwritten" each time the group is repeated, meaning that only the last match is captured.

In your example here, you're probably better off using `.split()`, in combination with a regex:

```
lun_q = 'Lun:\s*(\d+(?:\s+\d+)*)'
s = '''Lun: 0 1 2 3 295 296 297 298'''

r = re.search(lun_q, s)

if r:
    luns = r.group(1).split()

    # optionally, also convert luns from strings to integers
    luns = [int(lun) for lun in luns]
```

Comment: Picking `re.match()` vs `re.split()` is a non-trivial decision

Answer (score 8):

Another approach would be to use the regex you have to validate your data and then use a more specific regex that targets each item you wish to extract using a match iterator.

```
import re
s = '''Lun: 0 1 2 3 295 296 297 298'''
lun_validate_regex = re.compile(r'Lun:\s*((\d+)(\s\d+)*)')
match = lun_validate_regex.match(s)
if match:
    token_regex = re.compile(r"\d{1,3}")
    match_iterator = token_regex.finditer(match.group(1))
    for token_match in match_iterator:
        #do something brilliant
```

Comment: print re.findall('\d',s)

Answer (score 8):

If you are looking for an output such as 0,1,2,3,4 etc.:

```
print re.findall('\d', s)
```

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes, its easier without regex.

```
>>> s = '''Lun: 0 1 2 3 295 296 297 298'''
>>> if "Lun: " in s:
...     items = s.replace("Lun: ","").split()
...     for n in items:
...        if n.isdigit():
...           print n
...
0
1
2
3
295
296
297
298
```