# Regular expression group capture with multiple matches

Tags: python, regex

Quick regular expression question.
I'm trying to capture multiple instances of a capture group in python (don't think it's python specific), but the subsequent captures seems to overwrite the previous.

In this over-simplified example, I'm essentially trying to split a string:

```
x = 'abcdef'
r = re.compile('(\w){6}')
m = r.match(x)
m.groups()     # = ('f',) ?!?
```

I want to get `('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')`, but because regex overwrites subsequent captures, I get `('f',)`

Is this how regex is supposed to behave? Is there a way to do what I want without having to repeat the syntax six times?

Thanks in advance!
Andrew

Comment: I dont think so. There are re.findall and re.split for these problems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python regex multiple groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963691/python-regex-multiple-groups)

Comment: Here is a good article about Capturing a Repeated Group.
http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html Example: !abcabc123!
For capture both all abc and 123 need regex !((?:(abc)|(123))+)!. Note the additional brackets.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't use groups for this, I'm afraid.  Each group can match only once, I believe all regexes work this way.  A possible solution is to try to use findall() or similar.

```
r=re.compile(r'\w')
r.findall(x)
# 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'
```

Comment: bawk! *kicks can* Why can't it do exactly what I want how I want! --Thanks! Andrew

Comment: I have been looking for the command while trawling through `re.search` `re.match` and the returned `re.MatchObject`

Answer (score 9):

The [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module can do this.

```
> m = regex.match('(\w){6}', "abcdef")
> m.captures(1)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Also works with named captures:

```
> m = regex.match('(?P<letter>)\w)', "abcdef")
> m.capturesdict()
{'letter': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']}
```

The regex module is expected to replace the 're' module - it is a drop-in replacement that acts identically, except it has many more features and capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

To find all matches in a given string use [re.findall(regex, string)](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall). Also, if you want to obtain every letter here, your regex should be either `'(\w){1}'` or just `'(\w)'`.

See:

```
r = re.compile('(\w)')
l = re.findall(r, x)

l == ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your question is a simplified presentation of your need.

Then, I take an exemple a little more complex:

```
import re

pat = re.compile('[UI][bd][ae]')

ch = 'UbaUdeIbaIbeIdaIdeUdeUdaUdeUbeIda'

print [mat.group() for mat in pat.finditer(ch)]
```

result

```
['Uba', 'Ude', 'Iba', 'Ibe', 'Ida', 'Ide', 'Ude', 'Uda', 'Ude', 'Ube', 'Ida']
```