# multiple group matches for single regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm parsing a log with python and need quick fetch some values from it

this is the simple equivalent regex and usage example

```
pat = re.compile("(1(2[3456]+2)+1)*")
```

It doesn't work as expected, only the last match group is returned by pat.match().groups()

What is the simplest solution for such problems?

**updated** (as wiki engine says to use edit rather than creating new post):

I need repeated matches, of course.

```
to_match="1232112542254211232112322421"
```

regex find need to be applyed twice recursively. I can bear it, but is there any options?

Comment: Change `*` to `?`. `"(1(2[3456]+2)+1)?"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python regex multiple groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963691/), [Regular expression group capture with multiple matches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598340/), [Python regexes: How to access multiple matches of a group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060659/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, try this (but only after you learned how to accept answers ;-) )

```
s = "123321124421125521"
pat = re.compile("(1(2[3456]+2)+1)")
print pat.findall(s)
```

remove the quantifier and use instead `findall()`. This will result in this list:

> [('123321', '2332'), ('124421', '2442'), ('125521', '2552')]

Answer (score 1):

You are repeating a captured group instead of capturing a repeated group and that is the reason why you are getting only the last capture.

You should be using

```
pat = re.compile("((1(2[3456]+2)+1)*)")
```

See here for more on repeating a captured group vs capturing a repeated group http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html

Comment: It makes no sense to put brackets around the whole pattern. The match of the whole pattern is already stored in `.group(0)`. In your solution `.group(0)` and `.group(1)` are then the same.

Comment: @stema You are right, but evidently OP is looking at `group(1)` from what he says in the question. There is also a possibility that the regex given here is only the part of the actual regex that is causing OP a problem and there might be something to the left/right of the given regex in which case `group(0)` might not be what is needed.