# Regex to match a capturing group one or more times

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match pair of digits in a string and capture them in groups, however i seem to be only able to capture the last group.

```
Regex:
(\d\d){1,3}
```

Input String: 123456 789101

Match 1:    123456
  Group 1:  56

Match 2:    789101
  Group 1:  01

What I want is to capture all the groups like this:
Match 1:    123456
  Group 1:  12
  Group 2:  34
  Group 3:  56

*** Update**
It looks like Python does not let you capture multiple groups, for example in .NET you could capture all the groups in a single pass, hence re.findall('\d\d', '123456') does the job.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python regex multiple groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963691/), [Regular expression group capture with multiple matches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598340/), [Python regexes: How to access multiple matches of a group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060659/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do that using just a single regular expression.  It is a special case of counting, which you cannot do with just a regex pattern. \d\d will get you:

Group1: 12
Group2: 23
Group3: 34
...

regex library in python comes with a non-overlapping routine namely re.findall() that does the trick. as in:

```
     re.findall('\d\d', '123456')
```

will return `['12', '34', '56']`

Answer (score 2):

```
(\d{2})+(\d)?
```

I'm not sure how python handles its matching, but this is how i would do it

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import re
re.findall(r'\d\d','123456')
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want ? :

```
import re

regx = re.compile('(?:(?<= )|(?<=\A)|(?<=\r)|(?<=\n))'
                  '(\d\d)(\d\d)?(\d\d)?'
                  '(?= |\Z|\r|\n)')

for s in ('   112233  58975  6677  981  897899\r',
          '\n123456 4433 789101 41586 56 21365899 362547\n',
          '0101 456899 1 7895'):
    print repr(s),'\n',regx.findall(s),'\n'
```

result

```
'   112233  58975  6677  981  897899\r' 
[('11', '22', '33'), ('66', '77', ''), ('89', '78', '99')] 

'\n123456 4433 789101 41586 56 21365899 362547\n' 
[('12', '34', '56'), ('44', '33', ''), ('78', '91', '01'), ('56', '', ''), ('36', '25', '47')] 

'0101 456899 1 7895' 
[('01', '01', ''), ('45', '68', '99'), ('78', '95', '')]
```