# Regex Capture Multiple Phrases after One

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to figure out how to make regex capture a bunch of items only that come after one particular thing. I am using Python for this. One example of something like this would be using the text `B <4>.<5>  <6> A <1> m<2>  . <3>` with the intent of capturing only 1, 2, and 3. I thought a regular expression like  `A.*?<(.+?)>` would work, but it only caputures the final 3 using Python `re.findall`. Can I get any help with this?

Comment: Are you trying to capture the 1, 2, and 3 as separate groups or one group containing all of them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python regex multiple groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963691/python-regex-multiple-groups)

Comment: It doesn't matter to me, but I was originally trying to make them in separate groups.

Answer (score 2):

The [`regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) (going to replace `re` in future pythons) supports variable lookbehinds, which makes it fairly easy:

```
s = "B <4>.<5> <6> A23 <1> m<2> . <3>"

import regex
print regex.findall(r'(?<=A\d+.*)<.+?>', s)
# ['<1>', '<2>', '<3>']
```

(I'm using `A\d+` instead of just `A` to make thing interesting). If you're bound to the stock `re`, you're forced to ugly workarounds like this:

```
import re
print re.findall(r'(<[^<>]+>)(?=(?:.(?!A\d+))*$)', s)
# ['<1>', '<2>', '<3>']
```

or pre-splitting:

```
print re.findall(r'<.+?>', re.split(r'A\d+', s)[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier with a variable width lookbehind, but an alternate might be to make sure there's no `A` after the parts you're matching so that you can use something like:

```
re.findall(r'<(.+?)>(?![^A]*A[^A]*$)', 'B <4>.<5> <6> A <1> m<2> . <3>')
```

But here's a problem here... `(.+?)` accepts *anything* which can break what you're looking for. You can use a negated class: `[^>]+` instead of `.+?`.

This means:

```
re.findall(r'<([^>]+)>(?![^A]*A[^A]*$)', 'B <4>.<5> <6> A <1> m<2> . <3>')
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/tP0rJ4)

`(?![^A]*A[^A]*$)` makes sure there's no `A` ahead of the part you're capturing.

`(?! ... )` is a negative lookahead which makes the match fail if what's inside is matched.

`[^A]*` matches any character except `A`

`$` matches the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

As it currently stands, your code is matching text between `<` and `>` that comes after `A` followed by zero or more characters.  Furthermore, the only part of your text that fulfills this condition is `<1>` (which is why that is all that gets returned).

There are many ways to fix this problem, but I think the most straightforward is to first split on `A`, then use `<(.+?)>`:

```
>>> from re import findall, split
>>> text = 'B <4>.<5> <6> A <1> m<2> . <3>'
>>> text = split('A', 'B <4>.<5> <6> A <1> m<2> . <3>')
>>> text
['B <4>.<5> <6> ', ' <1> m<2> . <3>']
>>> text = text[1]
>>> text
' <1> m<2> . <3>'
>>> text = findall('<(.+?)>', text)
>>> text
['1', '2', '3']
>>>
```

Above is a step-by-step demonstration.  Below is the code you will want:

```
>>> text = 'B <4>.<5> <6> A <1> m<2> . <3>'
>>> findall('<(.+?)>', split('A', text)[1])
['1', '2', '3']
>>>
```

Comment: Isnt' it the other way around? (?.+) instead of (.+?) ?
I think you are trying to make a "non-greedy" search. Am I right?.
EDIT: You are right. It's (.+?) according to Python's reference.

Comment: No.  The way I put it makes it a non-greedy match.

Comment: @RobsonFrança `(?.+)` is not valid regex. `(?:.+)` maybe, but not `(?.+)`.