# Extract numbers from a string while maintaining the whitespaces

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x

I have some string like this

```
'    12    2    89   29   11    92     92     10'
```

(all the numbers are positive integers so no `-` and no `.`), and I want to extract all numbers from it, edit some of the numbers, and then put them all together with the same whitespaces. For example, if I change the number `11` to `22`, I want the final string as

```
'    12    2    89   29   22    92     92     10'
```

I did some search and most questions disregard the whitespaces and only care about the numbers. I tried

```
match = re.match((\s*(\d+)){8}, str)
```

but `match.group(0)` gives me the whole string,, `match.group(1)` gives me the first match `\    12` (I added the `\` otherwise the website won't show the leading whitespaces), and `match.group(2)` gives me `12`. But it won't give me any numbers after that, any index higher than `2` gives me an error. I don't think my approach is the correct one, what is the right way to do this?

I just tried `re.split('(\d+)', str)` and that seems to be what I need.

Comment: How about just `\s+\d+`. [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sckKLO/1)

Comment: What if you change 99 to 101? Should you lose a whitespace, or get a longer line?

Comment: already exists one answer at this link: [Python RegEx multiple groups
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963691/python-regex-multiple-groups)

Comment: @Evert Just keep the same number of of whitespace is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a regular expression with [non-capturing groups](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups), to get a list of 'space' parts and 'number' parts:

```
In [15]: text = '    12    2    89   29   11    92     92     10'
In [16]: parts = re.findall('((?: +)|(?:[0-9]+))', text)
In [17]: parts
Out[17]: ['    ', '12', '    ', '2', '    ', '89', '   ', '29', '   ',
  '11', '    ', '92', '     ', '92', '     ', '10']
```

Then you can do:

```
for index, part in enumerate(parts):
    if part == '11':
        parts[index] = '22'
replaced = ''.join(parts)
```

(or whatever match and replacement you want to do).

Answer (score 0):

Match all numbers with spaces, change desired number and join array.

```
import re

newNum = '125'
text = '    12    2    89   29   11    92     92     10'
                                              ^^
marray = re.findall(r'\s+\d+', text)
marray[6] = re.sub(r'\d+', newNum, marray[6])

print(marray) 

['    12', '    2', '    89', '   29', '   11', '    92', '     125', '     10']
```