# How to get multiple substrings from a matching string?

Tags: python, search, match, python-re

I am trying to extract some text from a string, in which I need to use a two level matching.

I have a string like

```
  s="Text_1 is abc: and Text_2 is def: also Text_3 is ghi:"
```

The result should be a list of the Text_x content like

```
  result = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

Is there a way to use it with a single match/search using brackts or similar to

```
 x= re.compile('Text_\d (\w+)\:')
 l = x.match(s)
```

I could not get it proper resolved.

I am using python 3.9

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx with multiple groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963691/regex-with-multiple-groups)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `re.findall` here:

```py
s = "Text_1 is abc: and Text_2 is def: also Text_3 is ghi:"
matches = re.findall(r'\bText_\d+ is (\w+(?: \w+)*):', s)
print(matches)  # ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```