# variable number of matched groups in a regex?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'd like to parse out strings like this (don't worry—this is only Node.JS which seems to sort of support unicode in RegEx):

```
var s = 'hello :你好:大家好:您好:吃饭了吗:';
console.log(s.match(/^([^ ]+) :([^:]+:)*/));
```

and get back groups of

```
[
    hello,
    你好:,
    大家好:,
    您好:,
    吃饭了吗:
]
```

However, right now, only `[hello, 吃饭了吗]` is the result.

Do I really need to split the results of the regex to achieve what I want?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to capture an arbitrary number of groups in JavaScript Regexp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537878/how-to-capture-an-arbitrary-number-of-groups-in-javascript-regexp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to. Groups only remember the last value they captured.