# Understanding a basic Javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript ,why

```
/^(\d{1}){3}$/.exec(123)
```

returns `["123", "3"]`, but

```
/^(\d{1})$/.exec(123)
```

returns `null` rather than `["3"]`.

Also, why is the first expression returning `3`, when `1` is the digit that follows `^` ?

Comment: Because that's what the regex says. This is ultra basic regex syntax; you should consult a reference, not StackOverflow.

Comment: The answer is related to the `^` and `$` anchors... Google it!

Comment: Also, `\d{1}` can be simplified to just `\d` - no quantifier means 1 - a quantifier of 1 is therefore pointless

Comment: `^` is start of string, `$` is end of string. Meaning first one matches a 3 character string, and captures a single number (because the brackets are only around a single `\d` instead of whole expression). The second rule says the whole string should be a single digit, as the `^` is before it, and `$` after it - hence "123" not matching this one

Comment: It doesn't match because you are looking for 1 character only.

    `^` = starts with
    `\d` = number
    `{1}` = maximum 1
    `$` = ends with

So you are asking for 1 number and nothing else. If you remove either the `^` or `$` or change your quantifier to `{3}` it will work.

Comment: After the edit by Sniffer, this seems worth an answer - it could go on to explain repeated sections of a regex (the `{3}`) and capture groups (why the first regex includes "3" in the results).

Comment: @Douglas The trouble is, it's not asking why the first expression matches 3 instead of 1 - it's just a lack of understanding of regex. This question is easily answered by a number of beginner tutorials around the internet.

Comment: sorry,I'm not good at English, but why 3 also  is returned in the first regex , since 3 does not follow ^?

Comment: ^ is special char meaning check the fist occurence in a multi char string

Answer (score 4):

### First case

Noting that `\d{1}` is equivalent to just `\d`,

```
/^(\d{1}){3}$/
```

can be simplified to

```
/^(\d){3}$/
```

which means

- begin of the string
- match a three-digit string
- end of the string

The parenthesis around `\d` define a capture group. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537878/how-to-capture-an-arbitrary-number-of-groups-in-javascript-regexp) and [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html), when you repeat a capturing group, the usual implementation keeps only the last capture.

That's why the final result is

```
[
  "123", // the whole matched string
  "3",   // the last captured group
]
```

---

### Second case

```
/^(\d{1})$/
```

can again be simplified to

```
/^(\d)$/
```

which means

- begin of the string
- match a single digit
- end of the string

Being `123` a three-digit string, it's not matched by the regex, so the result is `null`.