# Why is re.findall matching the string, but not returning the results correctly?

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to find a substring of the pattern `([A-Z][0-9]+)+` in another string.

One way to do this would be:

```
import re
re.findall("([A-Z][0-9]+)+", "asdf A0B52X4 asdf")[0]
```

Curiously, this yields `'X4'`, not `'A0B52X4'`, which was the result I expected.

Digging a bit into this, I also tried to just match the simple groups the string is composed of:

```
re.findall("[A-Z][0-9]+", "asdf A0B52X4 asdf")
```

Which yields the expected result: `['A0', 'B52', 'X4']`

And even more interesting:

```
re.findall("([A-Z][0-9]+){3,}", "asdf A0B52X4 asdf")
```

Which yields `['X4']`, but still seems to match the whole string I'm interested in, which is confirmed by trying `re.search` and using the result to obtain the substring manually:

```
m = re.search("([A-Z][0-9]+)+", "asdf A0B52X4 asdf")
m.string[m.start():m.end()]
```

This yields `'A0B52X4'`.

Now from what I know about regular expressions in python, parentheses not only just match the RE inside them, but also declare a "group" which lets you do all sorts of things with it. My theory would be that for some reason, `re.findall` only puts the last match of a group into the result string as opposed to the complete match.

Why does `re.findall` behave like this?

Comment: I closed the question as a duplicate of [How to capture an arbitrary number of groups in JavaScript Regexp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537878/how-to-capture-an-arbitrary-number-of-groups-in-javascript-regexp). This question isn't JavaScript, of course, but this is the same problem, it is explained well, and you can apply the same answer.

Comment: It is definitely not the best dupe for this question, as Python `re.findall` method is very specific and handles regex in a much more different way than any JS methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your matching group only matches one instance of the pattern at a time. The `+` just means to match all of them that occur in a row. It still only captures the first part of the match at one time.

Wrap your regex in an outer group, like this:

```
((?:[A-Z][0-9]+)+)
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/gX7pB8/1)