# How to capture all nested matches?

Tags: java, regex

I was trying to answer a question recently and while attempting to solve it, I ran into a question of my own.

Given the following code

```
private void regexample(){
    String x = "a3ab4b5";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\D+(\\d+)\\D+){2}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(x);
    while(m.find()){
        for(int i=0;i<=m.groupCount();i++){
            System.out.println("Group " + i + " = " + m.group(i));
        }
    }
}
```

And the output

```
Group 0 = a3ab4b
Group 1 = b4b
Group 2 = 4
```

Is there any straight-forward way I'm missing to get the value `3`?  The pattern should look for two occurrences of `(\\D+(\\d+)\\D+)` back-to-back, and `a3a` is part of the match.  I realize I can change expression to `(\\D+(\\d+)\\D+)` and then look for all matches, but that isn't technically the same thing.  Is the only way to do a double search?  ie:  Use the given pattern to match the string and then search again for each count of the outer group?

I guessed that the first values were overwritten with the second, but as I'm not that great with regex, I was hoping there was something I was missing.

Comment: When you repeat a capture group, the first capture is overwritten with the last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to capture multiple occurrences of the same group (with standard regex engines). You could use something like this:

```
Pattern.compile("(\\D+(\\d+)\\D+)(\\D+(\\d+)\\D+)");
```

Now, there are four groups instead of two, so you will get the values you expected.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537878/) deals with a similar problem.

Comment: In other words, "restructure your regex so you can get the value."  :)  Fair enough.

Comment: @MadConan: Note that `\\D+)(\\D+` implicitly requires at least 2 non digits between the 2 digits, and if there are more than 2 non-digits, the first part will take n - 1 characters, while the second part will take 1 character from the sequence of non-digits between the 2 numbers.