# Regular expression for custom syntax in text input

Tags: regex

I'm supposed to enforce a certain search-syntax in a text input, and after watching several RegEx videos and tutorials, I'm still having difficulties creating a regex for my purpose.
The expression structure should be something like that:

`$earch://site.com?y=7,   app=app1,  wu>7, cnt<>8,    url=http://kuku.com?adasd=343  ,   p=8`

may start with a free text search that may contain any character other than the delimiter, which is `,`. (free text must be first, and the string may be ONLY free text search).

after free text comma-separated parts of field names which consist only `[a-z][A-Z]`, followed by operator: `(=|<|>|<>)` and followed by field search value that may be anything but `,`.

between the commas that separate the parts there may be spaces `(\s*)`.

The free text part or at least one field=value must appear in order for the string to be valid.

Did anyone understand the question? :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood everything, but how's `^[^,]*(?:,\s*[a-zA-Z]+(?:[=><]|<>)[^,]+)*$`?

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. Why did you use non-capturing groups?
Plus - if I start out the string with a comma, it is valid, whereas I want it to not be valid (if there's no free text at the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

> `^[^,]*(?:,\s*[a-zA-Z]+(?:[=><]|<>)[^,]+)*$`? – Rawing
>
> Thanks, that seems to work. Why did you use non-capturing groups?

He did it most probably because he didn't assume that the groups are to be captured (you didn't specify that).

> Plus - if I start out the string with a comma, it is valid, whereas I
>   want it to not be valid (if there's no free text at the beginning).

That can be accomplished by changing the first `*` to a `+`, i. e. `^[^,]+…`

> I'm using javascript. I want to be able to separate each key=value
>   pair (including the possible free text as a group), and within that
>   group I would like to be able to capture key, operator, and value as
>   separate entities (or groups)

That's not doable with only one RegExp invocation, see e. g. [How to capture an arbitrary number of groups in JavaScript Regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3537914/2413201) Here's an example solution:

```js
s = '$earch://site.com?y=7,   app=app1,  wu>7, cnt<>8,    url=http://kuku.com?adasd=343  ,   p=8'
part = /,\s*([a-zA-Z]+)(<>|[=><])([^,]+)/
re = RegExp('^([^,]+)('+part.source+')*$')
freetext = re.exec(s)[1]  // validate s and take free text as 1st capture group of re
if (freetext)
{   document.write('free text:', freetext, '<p>')
    parts = RegExp(part.source, 'g')
    m = s.slice(freetext.length).match(parts) // now get all key=value pairs into m[]
    if (m)
    {   field = []
        for (i = 0; i < m.length; ++i)
        {   f = m[i].match(part) // and now capture key, operator and value from m[i]
            field[i] = { key:f[1], operator:f[2], value:f[3] }
            for (property in field[i]) // display them
                document.write(property, ':', field[i][property], '; ')
            document.write('<p>')
        }
        document.write(field.length, ' key/value pairs total<p>')
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. How can I make the expression capture the groups?

Comment: @nadavelyashiv: The group is capturing if we omit the `?:`, but … group**s**? There is only one group. How to retrieve multiple instances of it depends on the programming language used; you'd need to state it.

Comment: I'm using javascript. I want to be able to separate each key=value pair (including the possible free text as a group), and within that group I would like to be able to capture key, operator, and value as separate entities (or groups)

Comment: @nadavelyashiv: I expanded the answer accordingly.