# Python 3 REGEX assistance

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am currently trying to scan a file for a specific pattern and capture pieces of the matched pattern to use in a replacement string.

My current Python 3 script is using this pattern and captures the data in simple cases.

```
    def readFile(filename):
        pattern = re.compile(b"(<%InsertIf expression=\"\$\{\(\((.*?)\[\'(.*?)\'\].*?\'(.*?)\'\)\)\}\".*?\/InsertIf%>)", re.DOTALL)
        with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
            data = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
            for match in re.finditer(pattern, data):
                print(match.groups())
                print ("")
```

For example, when matching this snippet of the file:

```
<%InsertIf expression="${((user.MemberAttribute['treatmentcode'] == 'NM'))}" %>some random text goes here<sup>®</sup> membership<%/InsertIf%><%InsertIf expression="${((user.MemberAttribute['treatmentcode'] == 'N1'))}" %>some random text goes here<sup>®</sup> upgrade.<%/InsertIf%><br />
```

I obtain the desired output from the regex I have in place for these patterns:

```
(b'<%InsertIf expression="${((user.MemberAttribute[\'treatmentcode\'] == \'NM\'))}" %>some random text goes here<sup>\xc2\xae</sup> membership<%/InsertIf%>', b'user.MemberAttribute', b'treatmentcode', b'NM')

(b'<%InsertIf expression="${((user.MemberAttribute[\'treatmentcode\'] == \'N1\'))}" %>some random text goes here<sup>\xc2\xae</sup> upgrade.<%/InsertIf%>', b'user.MemberAttribute', b'treatmentcode', b'N1')
```

However, when the InsertIf expression has additional conditionals, I cannot figure out the appropriate pattern to use for the regex.

Here is a two complex snippets which I am trying resolve. In one case there is an additional '||' conditional. In the other there is an "and" conditional.

```
<%InsertIf expression="${((user.MemberAttribute['country'] == 'US') || (user.MemberAttribute['country'] == 'CA'))}" %>
```

In the above case I would expect a second set of captures:

1. Full InsertIf captured string
2. user.MemberAttribute
3. country
4. US
5. user.MemberAttribute
6. country
7. CA

But since the pattern doesn't account for the conditional the 4th capture returns:
4.  US') || (user.MemberAttribute['country'] == 'CA

AND example

```
<%InsertIf expression="${((user.MemberAttribute['country']=='US') and (user.MemberAttribute['treatmentcode']=='NM'))}" %><%InsertCSE id="XXXXX"%><%/InsertIf%>
```

Similar expectations and bad result as the '||' example above.

Any assistance with the pattern is greatly appreciated. I am still learning regular expressions and this one is just a tad out of my depth.

Thanks.

Adding additional details as requested:
I am essentially trying to perform a conversion of one syntax to another within a file.

Example: I want to find this pattern...

```
<%InsertIf 
expression="${((user.MemberAttribute['treatmentcode']=='NM'))}" %>
<%InsertCSE id="4000116068"%><%/InsertIf%>
<%InsertElse expression="${((user.MemberAttribute['treatmentcode']=='N1'))}" %>
<%InsertCSE id="4000116069"%>
<%/InsertElse%>
```

and convert it to this pattern while preserving the variable values:

```
%%[ if treatmentcode == "NM" then ]%%
%%=contentArea("4000116068")=%%
%%[ elseif treatmentcode == "N1" then ]%%
%%=contentArea("4000116069")=%%
%%[ endif ]%%
```

The challenge comes into play when there are additional conditionals as part of the expression itself. The original snippets above show more of the details for the input. I can get simple expressions working as desired but it falls apart on the more complex statements.

I was initially trying to take a simple InsertIf case and get it working. I could then loop the file to handle the InsertElse and other cases.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible. The closest I got was to have the last occurrence of the pattern always matched (I only tried the `||` sample). `(<%InsertIf expression="\${\((?:\((.*?\..*?)\['(.*?)'\] == '(.*?)'\)(?: \|\| )?)+\)}"\s?%>.*?<%\/InsertIf%>)`. This may help you understand why, as the same applies to Python as to JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3537914/1476989

Comment: You can test out the Regex I made here: http://regexr.com/3dljk

Comment: You only get as many group values as there are groups in your regex, if you do not define 7 groups, you can't get more. What if you have 7 `||` conditions? Can you use PyPi `regex` module? There, you can use `.captures` collection.

Comment: Thanks pgmann and wiktor stribizew. I've been testing various patterns using http://pythex.org/ which is a similar tool. I do understand that the number of groups returned is based upon the groups defined in the regex. I guess I was hoping for a magical looping regex that could lookahead for the  conditional expressions. It may in fact be impossible but I wanted to seek advice before throwing in the towel. I may be better off capturing the entire group and manipulating the string in a couple of steps.

Comment: Could you please share an input string, and the expected output? So that we could answer the question.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/vFBTyg

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I added more detail to the original post to try and address your request. Your ideone.com post certainly gives me more insight on approaches to take. Thank you.

Comment: Your title should be a brief, specific description of your problem.

Comment: Hi, I've hit that `InsertIf` `expression` syntax, but can't find any documentation about it: can you point me to any?

Answer (score 0):

Give you an idear to solve the first problem.
You can take two steps:

1. get the whole expression with pattern:

   `re.compile(b"(<%InsertIf expression=\"\$\{\(\((.*?)\)\)\}\".*?\/InsertIf%>)", re.DOTALL)`
2. When you get the context, you can use another pattern to find name, attribute, and value

   `([^\[]*)\[\'([^\']*)\'\].*?\'([^\']*)\'`

   here, I'd like use `[\']*` or `[\[]*` instead of `.*?`

using `findall()` to find all matches.

The second problem which is convert a "language" to another needs getting more infomation like `==`