# Capture words by excluding a non-capturing group of repeating words

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I want to extract everything from the string below, except *"from"* and *", from"*:

> from Old French, from Latin innocentia, from innocent- ‘not harming’ (based on nocere ‘injure’).

This is my regex:

```
(?:from)(.*)(?:,.from)(.*)
```

For this regex, I will get  `Old French, from Latin innocentia` and `innocent- ‘not harming’ (based on nocere ‘injure’).` as a result. How do I edit my regex snippet so that it can match the expected conditions without repeating the non-capturing group `(?:,.from)`?

The result should be:

- `Old French`
- `Latin innocentia`
- `innocent- ‘not harming’ (based on nocere ‘injure’).`

Comment: What is the language you are in?

Comment: I'm using Node JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
line="from Old French, from Latin innocentia, from innocent- ‘not harming’ (based on nocere ‘injure’)."
line.split(/, from|from/)
```

=>

```
[ '',
 ' Old French',
 ' Latin innocentia',
 ' innocent- ‘not harming’ (based on nocere ‘injure’).' ]
```

Which might be close enough.
Try online: https://repl.it/Chp8

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a regex to split the string. This will return the same results with better speed than using the backtracking nightmare `.*`.

You could use this regex (based off yours) to do so:

```
(,.)?from
```

More information on splitting can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: Thank you. Your answer also helped me. Aside from the `split` function. Is there no way around this using pure regex?

Comment: @DuyNguyen Not with normal JS regex repeated capture groups. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3537914/6083675