# javascript regex - can't get correct pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following input string:

```
  02:00:00_03:00:00_1234@someemail.or.domain.com
```

or this :

```
  02:00:00_03:00:00_mtwrf_1234@someemail.or.domain.com
```

I'm trying to write a javascript regex that will match both. 
The "*mtwrf*" is optional... it may or may not be present in the input.

I've been using this site to test: 
http://www.regexpal.com/

This pattern:

```
  (\d\d\:\d\d:\d\d\_){2}([mtwrfsn\_]*)([\w\d]+\@?[\w\d\.]+)
```

seems to work as per the regexpal.com website using the input string:

```
  02:00:00_03:00:00_mtw_1234@test.domain.com
```

But ... when I plug that into my code... it's not matching / finding the "02:00:00".

Here's my javascript code:

```
       var pattern  = /(\d\d\:\d\d:\d\d\_){2}([mtwrfsn\_]*)([\w\d]+\@?[\w\d\.]+)/;
            if (rules_array[i].length > 0) {
                    searchval = rules_array[i].match(pattern);
            }
            console.log(searchval);
```

And the output I get is this:

```
[ '02:00:00_03:00:00_1234@test.domain.com',
  '03:00:00_',
  '',
  '1234@test.domain.com',
  index: 0,
  input: '02:00:00_03:00:00_1234@test.domain.com' ]
```

I think i should be seeing something like this instead:

```
[ '02:00:00_03:00:00_1234@test.domain.com',
  '02:00:00_',
  '03:00:00_',
  '1234@test.domain.com',
  index: 0,
  input: '02:00:00_03:00:00_1234@test.domain.com' ]
```

Can you see where my bug / problem is? 
Thanks.

Comment: When using repeated capturing groups, the captured content of this group will be replaced each time the group is matched.

Comment: I recommend [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/) : `((\d{2}:){2}\d{2}_){2}.*@.*.com`

Comment: @SebastianProske oh... so do you mean then that I should get rid of references to things like "{2}" in my pattern?

Comment: Yes, just use `/(\d\d\:\d\d:\d\d\_)(\d\d\:\d\d:\d\d\_)([mtwrfsn_]*)(\w+(?:@[\w.]+)?)/`

Comment: That worked guys.  Thanks @SebastianProske

Comment: You can use: `/\b(?:\d{2}[_:]){6}(?:mtwrfsn_)?(?:[\w\d]+@[\w\d.]+)/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you encountered is related to *repeated capturing groups*, see [*How to capture an arbitrary number of groups in JavaScript Regexp?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537878/how-to-capture-an-arbitrary-number-of-groups-in-javascript-regexp).

However, the solution for your case is to just spell out the capturing group for the second time value:

```js
var pattern  = /(\d\d\:\d\d:\d\d_)(\d\d\:\d\d:\d\d_)([mtwrfsn_]*)(\w+?[\w.]+)/;
var searchval = "02:00:00_03:00:00_mtw_1234@test.domain.com".match(pattern);
console.log(searchval);
```

yielding

```
[
  "02:00:00_03:00:00_mtw_1234",
  "02:00:00_",
  "03:00:00_",
  "mtw_",
  "1234"
]
```

The pattern may be further shortened, just note that `[\w\d]` = `\w` since `\w` matches digits as well as `\d`.