# Regex to find any double quoted string within a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get a regex that will find a double quoted strings within a double quoted string.  For example:

"some text "string 1" and "another string" etc"

I would like to pick out "string 1" and "another string".

I got as far as `\"[^\"]*\"` but this will match "some text " in the example.  I basically need to ignore the first and last quotes and match within that.

Edit: The example mentioned doesn't have literal quotes surrounding it, but it is a Javascript string.  The example regex is matching the entire string first. My Javascript is as follows.

```js
var string = 'some "text" etc';
var pattern = new RegExp('\"[^\"]*\"/g');
var result = pattern.exec(string);
console.log("result: ", string);
// some "text" etc
```

So it could be my implementation of regex in Javascript that is the problem.

Comment: You may use your regex  after removing the leading and trailing quotes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, I've edited my post to hopefully explain why I can't do that.

Comment: Your regex declaration is incorrect. What I meant is something like `var result = string.replace(/^"+|"+$/g, '').match(/"[^"]*"/g)`. Besides, in your code, you just print the input string, not the regex result.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't escape the `"`. And just look for the text between quotes (in non greedy mode `.*?`) like:

```js
var string = 'some text "string 1" and "another string" etc';

var pattern = /".*?"/g;

var current;
while(current = pattern.exec(string))
    console.log(current);
```

Comment: Yes, because in JavaScript you can't match the first quotes, then repetitively match sub quote groups and get all captures in one shot (like you can in .Net). http://stackoverflow.com/a/3537914/1236397

Comment: @Bryan you're welcome! Learn more about **Greediness** [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions).

Comment: `var pattern = /"[^"]*"/g` might turn out a better alternative.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The non greedy mode is exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

This works also:

```
var s = "\"some text \"string 1\" and \"another string\" etc\"" ""some text "string 1" and "another string" etc""
s.match(/(?!^)".*?"/g)

Result: [""string 1"", ""another string""]
```

The negative look ahead will not match the first quote because it's at the beginning, causing all others to match, ignoring the last one, since it doesn't have another quote following. This assumes there won't be any white space before the first quote of course.