# Compound Words - Regex

Tags: regex

Is it possible to match and get the capture groups of compound title case words?

ie:  *This is a **FooBar** test*

So *FooBar* is matched and the capture groups are **Foo** and **Bar**.

I have this `([A-Z][a-z]+){2,}` which matches but only captures 1 group *Bar*

I'm using the Lucene regular expression engine.

Thanks

Comment: From the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537878/how-to-capture-an-arbitrary-number-of-groups-in-javascript-regexp): *"When you repeat a capturing group, in most flavors, only the last capture is kept; any previous capture is overwritten."* I don't know which regex flavour you're using, but it looks like this is what's happening.

Comment: ([A-Z]+[a-z]+[A-Z]+[a-z]+)

Comment: @MrMysteryGuest that gives 1 capture of _FooBar_

Comment: @BenG - Can't you split that or are you trying to do two things at once?