# Matching multiple regex groups in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having trouble getting my regex to match all groups.

My regex: `/^#(\\|?[^|]+\\|[^|]+\\|?)+?$/g`

Test string: `#something|somethingelse|morestuff|evenmorestuff`

The matches I want are the things matches in pairs, as in: `something|somethingelse` and `morestuff|evenmorestuff` should be groups 1 and 2. But I can only get the last group to return.

My code looks like this (I'm using Javascript).

```
re = new RegExp('^#(\\|?[^|]+\\|[^|]+\\|?)+?$', 'g');
var matches = re.exec(window.location.hash);
console.log([matches[0], matches[1], matches[2]]);
```

`matches[0]` returns the whole string
`matches[1]` returns `morestuff|evenmorestuff`
`matches[2]` is undefined.

Comment: Do not use repeated capturing groups, use multiple matching and validate separately if necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, do you mean I should specify a finite amount of matches and not loop through them?

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is an example of how [repeated capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537878/how-to-capture-an-arbitrary-number-of-groups-in-javascript-regexp) works: `(ab)+` only captures the last occurrence of `ab` in an `abababab` string.

In your case, you may perform two steps: 1) validate the input string to make sure it follows the pattern you want, 2) extract parts from the string using a `g` based regex.

To validate the string you may use

```
/^#[^|]+\|[^|]+(?:\|[^|]+\|[^|]+)*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0Jvr7Q/2). It is basically your original regex but it is more efficient, has no capturing groups (we do not need them at this step), and it does not allow `|` at the start / end of the string (but you may add `\|*` after `#` and before `$` if you need that).

**Details**

- `^#` - `#` at the start of the string
- `[^|]+` - 1+ chars other than `|`
- `\|` - a `|`
- `[^|]+` - 1+ chars other than `|`
- `(?:\|[^|]+\|[^|]+)*`  - 0+ sequences of

  - `\|`  - a `|` char
  - `[^|]+\|[^|]+` - 1+ chars other than `|`, `|` and again 1+ chars other than `|`
- `$` - end of string.

To extract the pairs, you may use a simple [`/([^|]+)\|([^|]+)/`](https://regex101.com/r/0Jvr7Q/3) regex (the input will be the substring starting at Position 1).

Whole solution:

```js
var s = "#something|somethingelse|morestuff|evenmorestuff";
var rx_validate = /^#[^|]+\|[^|]+(?:\|[^|]+\|[^|]+)*$/;
var rx_extract = /([^|]+)\|([^|]+)/g;
var m, result = [];
if (rx_validate.test(s)) {
  while (m=rx_extract.exec(s.substr(1))) {
    result.push([m[1], m[2]]);
  }
}
console.log(result);
// or just pairs as strings
// console.log(s.substr(1).match(rx_extract));
// => [ "something|somethingelse",  "morestuff|evenmorestuff" ]
```