# Regular expression for capturing groups' return value

Tags: javascript, regex

The regular expression is

```js
'Gogogo now!'.match(/(go)+/i)
```

the match method without g flag will return all the capturing groups, from my understanding, the expression will return

```js
['Gogogo', 'Go', 'Gogo', 'Gogogo']
```

but when I execute the expression, its return value is

```js
["Gogogo","go"]
```

Can anyone explain for me why?

Comment: _"the match method without g flag will return all the capturing groups"_ That is [not true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3537914/8967612).

Comment: Without the `g` it will only return **one** result. The `g` flag means find all results. Your understanding is the opposite of reality

Answer (score 1):

> the match method without g flag will return all the capturing groups

No, that's not true. In Javascript, when a capturing group is repeated, only the last capture is returned. The `g` flag is irrelevant here. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3537914/8967612) for more information.

**Then why does `match()` return an array with two elements?**

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) tells you that the return value is:

> An Array whose contents depend on the presence or absence of the
> global (g) flag, or null if no matches are found.
>
> - If the g flag is used, all results matching the complete regular expression will be returned, but capturing groups will not.
> - if the g flag is not used, only the first complete match and its related capturing groups are returned. In this case, the returned item
>   will have additional properties as described below.

So, in your example, the returned array contains the following two elements:

1. The full match.
2. The *last* capture that was captured by group #1.

Comment: What does  its related capturing groups mean?

Comment: Well, consider a pattern like `a(b)(c)`. It contains **two capturing groups**. So, when matched against "abc", if the `g` flag  is _not_ used, the returned array will include both groups along with the full match (i.e., `['abc', 'b', 'c']`) and if the `g` flag is used, the returned array will only include the full match (i.e., `'abc'`). Your pattern, on the other hand, only has one capturing group (remember, a repeated capturing group only count as one; the last capture).

Answer (score -1):

Here is an explanation and demonstration

https://regex101.com/r/iNntVP/3

Notice this part of the explanation:

> A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data

Your result array contains the Full match (`Gogogo`) and the last iteration (`go`)