# Regular expression for pandoc-markdown citations

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to search and replace citations from pandoc-markdown.
They have the following syntax:

```
[prenote @autorkey, postnote]
```

Or for more than one Author

```
[prenote1 @authorekey1, postnote1; prenote2 @authorkey2, postnote2]
```

The pre-notes, the author-keys and the post-notes should each be in their own capture group.

For only one author in a citation I used regex this:

```regex
\[((.*) )?@(.*?)(, (.*))?\]
```

But I can't figure out how to match a citation with multiple authors.
Ideally it would be possible to match citations with one or more author keys.
The pre-note and the post-note should be optional.

Is this possible?

Comment: _"The pre-notes, the author-keys and the post-notes should each be in their own capture group"_. What you're trying to do is capturing a dynamic number of capturing groups, ie repeating a capturing group. It won't work this way (Source: a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3537914/4375327) linking to a [detailled article](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html)).

Answer (score 1):

We need more context with code (full sample code) to be able to answer fully, so I can only answer in the same general way in which you asked the question.

I do not believe you can do it in one operation with one regular expression.

So the overall technique I would use is:

1. First match the entire citation (with one or more authors) using a simple regex with only one group, namely for everything between `[` and `]`.
2. Then, when a match is found, split what is in that match (i.e. everything between the square brackets) by `;` to get a list of `"prenote @authorkey, postnote"` strings.
3. Do the wanted replacements on each element in that resulting list of single author strings.
4. Stitch together the final citation by joining the resulting list with semicolons again and adding `[` and `]` in around it.
5. Put that final citation in the original instead of the matched string.

You can put steps 2 to 4 in a function `f(match_object)`, and then use [`re.sub(pattern, f, string)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to do the replacement. It will call function `f` for each match it finds, and replace that match with the return value of `f`.

Answer (score 0):

You might make use of the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) to get the 3 capturing groups.

```
(?:\G(?!^)|\[(?=[^][\r\n]*\]))[^\S\r\n]*(.*?) @(.*?), ([^][,\r\n]*)[\];]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nyDxlw/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##TY@7bsMwDEV3fQXrSUqEoE63BIazdevS0bILo2Uco7Uk0DTQAP13V/IjCRc9eA7B6698cfZlHNvOO2IgbPBXCF8zI1nIgBKZH8yrzJ8q9WcKmWdFVRaGjC03plSqqMz7/JK7Ta7gNB0aZMT03FGFKY9lIgRjzx89U5grk8ITWscIp3pgR9941eBdz/GvNDYR8FA3Op3wiyMMQno30iMsxH4lArC/A/s4UwnR1fx5wT5Gi1l359Z@tSGsXDJrWLcM8NkRTMLb0On5Bq0FtEOHVDPKZZqGnmviLFWHae3oNeQGH7woUG0blM8aftDOzm5q91KpRYl1U7L7dQupuAGeWsvwOEGuoArrjuM/)

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
  - `|` Or
  - `\[(?=[^][\r\n]*\])` Match `[` and assert that there is a closing `]`
- `)` Close non capture group
- `[^\S\r\n]*` Match 0+ occurrences of a whitespace char except a newline
- `(.*?)` Capture **group 1**, match any char except a newline as least as possible
- `@` Match literally
- `(.*?)` Capture **group 2**, match any char except a newline as least as possible
- `,`  Match literally
- `([^][,\r\n]*)` Capture **group 3**, match any char except `]` `[` `,` or a newline
- `[\];]` Match either `]` or `;`

Example code using regex.finditer

```
import regex

pattern = r"(?:\G(?!^)|\[(?=[^][\r\n]*\]))[^\S\r\n]*(.*?) @(.*?), ([^][,\r\n]*)[\];]"

test_str = ("[prenote @autorkey, postnote]\n"
            "[prenote1 @authorekey1, postnote1; prenote2 @authorkey2, postnote2]\n")

matches = regex.finditer(pattern, test_str)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print (match.group(groupNum))
```

Output

```
prenote
autorkey
postnote
prenote1
authorekey1
postnote1
prenote2
authorkey2
postnote2
```